# ORDER BY in query not working with loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

If you see in this image...

[image]

The username pfar54 appears twice. I have a query that has this ordering method..

```
ORDER BY up.ordering
```

If the user has an `ordering` of 2 then I want the players name to appear in the second input and not create another column.

This is all I have in my playersByUser db...

```
id userid playername    ordering
1  1      Tom Brady     1
2  85     Aaron Rodgers 1
3  1     Eddie Lacey    2
```

For some reason it is looping through everything instead of ordering it by the ordering column. The page should look more like this..

```
pfar54      Big Daddy
Tom Brady   Aaron Rodgers
Eddie Lacey
```

What am I doing wrong with either my `SELECT` query or loop that makes doesn't allow the user to have multiple players in one row rather than creating a new column for a new player?

```
try {
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", ""); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
    exit(); 
} 
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT up.ordering, u.id, u.username, up.playername 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN playersByUser AS up ON u.id = up.userid 
WHERE u.group IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY up.ordering");
if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User/Player SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User/Player SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
 $stmt->store_result();
} catch (Exception $e ) {
    die("User/Player SELECT execute() failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
$stmt->bind_result($ordering, $userid, $username, $playername);
 <form action="" method="POST"> 
<?php

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $playersArray[['userid']]=['playername'];
?>
    <div class="draftResultsWrap"> 
        <div class="inline"> 
        <?php echo "<div>" . $username . "</div>"; ?> 
        </div>
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='1 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='2 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='3 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='4 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='5 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='6 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='7 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='8 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='9 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='10 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='11 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='12 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
            <input type="text" name="playerarray<?php echo $userid; ?>[]" class="draftBorder" value='13 <?php echo $playername;?>'/> 
        </div> 
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: You have two players with `userid = 1`, so they get put in different rows of the output. What's confusing about that?

Comment: It is the same user. The players are the names like Aaron Rodgers, tom Brady, etc. Rather than having a bunch of columns I did it like this. I was wanting the ordering column put the player in the correct input. Ie ordering number 2 be put into the second input of the user ID it is associated with.

Comment: You're not doing any grouping, so you get one row in the results for each `PlayersByUser` row that's matched.

Comment: @Barmar How could I do grouping to get what I am trying to?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="draftResultsWrap">
    <tr><th>Username</th><th>Playername</th></tr>
<?php while ($stmt->fetch()){?>
  <?php echo "
     <tr>
       <td><input name='username[$userid]' value='$username'/></td>
       <td><input name='playername[$userid]' value='$playername'/></td>
     </tr>
  "; ?>

<?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I need the while loop to go into the inputs.

Comment: What are the inputs for ? I don't get it.

Comment: To echo out the player name. The inputs will be blank to start from and I am entering in the names from those inputs.

Comment: Edited, I think that's what you want but not sure.
If it's not it, please tell exactly what you want in your main post.